# Check if it is a specific type - haskell

Tags: haskell

I thought it would be really easy to find the answer online but I had no luck with that. Which means that my question should't be a question but I am sure more people new to Haskell might come up with the same question.

So how do I check if a value is of a certain type?

I have the following data type defined and I wanna check whether the input on a function is of a specific type.

`data MyType a = MyInt Int | MyOther a (MyType a)`

Comment: you don't - in Haskell there is no type-information at runtime - instead you constraint your functions: `myFun :: Num a => NewType a -> ...`

Comment: `data NewType a = Int | a (NewType a)` is illegal. You're using type variable `a` as if it were a value constructor; you can't do that.

Comment: You've changed your question (`Num` -> a certain type). That means there's now a technically correct answer to your question, the `Data.Typeable` API. You may still have an X/Y problem here: Without seeing your exact usecase, my hunch is that you *shouldn't* actually use `Typeable` for it, as it's bad style to use it when proper static typing is enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your `data` declaration will not work. Let's assume you're using this type:

```
data MyType a = MyInt Int | MyOther a (MyType a)
```

then you can have functions that take a `MyType a`, some specific `MyType` (e.g. `MyType Int`) or a constrained `MyType` (e.g. `Num a => MyType a`).

If you want to know whether you have a `MyInt` or a `MyOther`, you can simply use pattern matching:

```
whichAmI :: MyType a -> String
whichAmI (MyInt i) = "I'm an Int with value " ++ show i
whichAmI (MyOther _ _) = "I'm something else"
```

When you want to know if the type in the parameter `a` is a `Num`, or what type it is, you will run into a fundamental Haskell limitation. Haskell is statically typed so there is no such dynamic checking of what the `a` in `MyType a` is.

The solution is to limit your function if you need a certain type of `a`. For example we can have:

```
mySum :: Num a => MyType a -> a
mySum (MyInt i) = fromIntegral i
mySum (MyOther n m) = n + mySum m
```

or we can have a function that only works if `a` is a `Bool`:

```
trueOrGE10 :: MyType Bool -> Bool
trueOrGE10 (MyInt i) = i >= 10
trueOrGE10 (MyOther b _) = b
```

As with all Haskell code, it will need to be possible to determine at compile-time whether a particular expression you put into one of these functions has the right type.